# Get row of data for MAX value over GROUP BY and JOINS

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group

I am working with the ml100k dataset to write a query that can fetch me the most rated movie for every age. 
Here's how my tables are defined. 
**users** 
`id | age | gender | occupation | zipcode` 
**ratings** 
`userid | movieid | rating | ts`

What I've done so far

1. Since the count wasn't explicitly defined, I wrote a query to find it.

```
   SELECT age, movieid, COUNT(*) AS mcount
   FROM ratings
   JOIN users ON id = userid
   GROUP BY age, movieid
```

This gave me the count for every movie for every age.

```
10  1   1
11  1   1
13  1   3
14  1   1
15  1   2
16  1   4
17  1   4
18  1   6
19  1   15
20  1   22
21  1   14
```

2. To find the maximum for each age

```
    SELECT age, MAX(mcount) AS mc
    FROM (
        SELECT age, movieid, COUNT(*) AS mcount
        FROM ratings
        JOIN users ON id = userid
        GROUP BY age, movieid
    ) t1
    GROUP BY age
```

```
7   1
10  1
11  1
13  5
14  3
15  5
16  5
17  11
18  16
19  21
20  25
21  23
```

This gave me the age and the max count. However, I also want the corresponding movie ID and this where I have been stuck. My thought process is to join these results with the first table but it is not working. Are there any other alternatives I can try?
This is the query I used.

```
SELECT users.age, ratings.movieid, count(*) as mc2
FROM ratings JOIN users ON id = userid 
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT age, MAX(mcount) AS mc
    FROM (
        SELECT age, movieid, COUNT(*) AS mcount
        FROM ratings
        JOIN users ON id = userid
        GROUP BY age, movieid
    ) t1
    GROUP BY age
)t2
ON t2.age = users.age
WHERE mc2=t2.mc
GROUP BY users.age, ratings.movieid;
```

Comment: What is MySQL version precisely?

Comment: @Akina It is 8.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT t.age, t.movieid, t.mcount
FROM (
   SELECT age, movieid, COUNT(*) AS mcount
   FROM ratings
   JOIN users ON id = userid
   GROUP BY age, movieid
) t
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT age, movieid, COUNT(*) AS mcount
   FROM ratings
   JOIN users ON id = userid
   GROUP BY age, movieid
) t2
ON t.age = t2.age AND
   t.movieid <> t2.movieid AND
   t.mcount < t2.mcount
WHERE t2.age IS NULL
```

Explanation:

- first subselect

  - joins `ratings` and `users`
  - `on` the `id` of `users`
  - groups by `age` and `movieid`
  - to find the groups
  - selects the fields you need
  - yields all groups
- second subselect

  - is the same as the first
- we `LEFT JOIN` the two groups by

  - matching `age`
  - different `movieid` (so we will have sensible count comparisons)
  - and the first `mcount` being smaller than the second
  - because we want to find items of the first group
  - which do not have higher count matches
  - so we search for higher count matches
- and in the `WHERE` clause we exclude the scenario when we found higher count matches in the second group than in the first group

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f8defe/6

Answer (score 1):

> It is 8.2.0 – vnk

```
WITH cte AS (
        SELECT age, 
               movieid, 
               COUNT(*) AS mcount, 
               RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY age, ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rnk
        FROM ratings
        JOIN users ON id = userid
        GROUP BY 1, 2
        )
SELECT age, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(movieid) movie_ids, 
       mcount
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1
GROUP BY 1, 3
```

More than one movie may have the same and maximal rating. So an aggregation is added to the outer query. If you want to receive these duplicates not in one output row but in a lot of rows, one movie per row, then remove outer aggregation.

If you need only one movie then you must define additional ordering criteria (expand ORDER BY in the window definition) which allows to select only one movie from all possible ones.

Or, if you need in any indefinite/random of them , then simply remove outer aggregation and use ROW_NUMBER() instead of RANK().